# keymapp with kmacro keymaps

Tags: keymap

Why evals `(keymapp 'kmacro-keymap)` to `t`,
and `(keymapp 'kmacro-step-edit-map)`  to `nil`?

Both look like ordinary keymaps to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function (predicate) `keymapp` tests the value of its argument to see if it is a keymap. In both cases, the sexps you provide pass a *symbol* as the argument, not a keymap.

However, as a special case `keymapp` also accepts a symbol whose **function** definition is a keymap. That is the case for `kmacro-keymap` but not for `kmacro-step-edit-map`. You can check this by applying function `symbol-function` to each of those symbols.

What you probably want to do is not pass an argument that evaluates to a symbol, but pass a symbol whose **variable** value is a keymap:

```
(keymapp kmacro-keymap)
(keymapp kmacro-step-edit-map)
```

Those both return `t`, as the value of each of those variables is a keymap.

Why the special case for an argument that is not, itself, a keymap but is instead a symbol whose function definition is a keymap?  This is more or less a convenience.  When would you want/need to define a symbol's *function* definition as a keymap?  To be able to bind that function as a prefix key.

See the Elisp manual, node [Prefix Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html).  There you see this:

> A “prefix key” is a key sequence whose binding is a keymap.

That means that the function that is bound to the key is itself a keymap.  A symbol is made to be such a keymap-valued function by setting its function definition (its `symbol-function`) to the keymap.  You can do this using function `define-prefix-command`.

Comment: Very useful answer, it even answered my next question: why keymaps also store to function's definition, thank you! So I was biten by the various symbol components. Could you tell me why `(symbol-function 'kmacro-keymap)` and `(symbol-value 'kmacro-keymap)` both eval to the same keymap? Isn't that wasted memory?

Comment: Nevermind my question about wasted memory. Manual indicates, that it is stored via function indirection facilities.